# How can i know when recharts chart is ready (lines already appear and animation ended)?

Tags: recharts

I want to copy a chart to the clipboard. I'm doing it by converting the chart to a canvas using `html2canvas` npm package.

Is there any event I can listen to that will indicate that the lines in the chart are already drawn and i can safely copy to clipboard?

Right now if i'm not waiting long enough I get an empty chart.

Answer (score 2):

You can make us of the `onAnimationEnd` props of any chart component like `<Line>`, `<Bar>`, `<Pie>` or whatever you are using. Just to make it clear; it is not defined for `LineChart` but `Line` component itself.

I think it is not documented, but works like a charm.

```
<LineChart width={730} height={250} data={data}
  margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" onAnimationEnd={this.copyToCanvas} />
</LineChart>
```